# what is the default value of an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

If I were to create an array with `int* array = new int[10];` and fill part of the array with values, how can I check how much of the array is filled? I want to loop through and check if each value is the default value but I'm not sure what the default value of each array element is. Would it be `null` `0` or garbage values?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how to set a default value in C++ when making an array.

```
int array[100] = {0};
```

Now every element is set to `0`. Without doing this every element it garbage and will be undefined behavior if used.

Not all languages are like this. Java has default values when declaring a data structure but C++ does not.

Comment: Beware! This can't set other value (e.g. `1`) to the array. I propose to edit this answer by removing the misleading `{0}` and replacing it with an empty curly-braces `{}`.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo Specifically, `{x, y, z}` = `{x, y, z, 0, 0, 0, ...}`. Hence `{0}` = `{0, 0, 0, 0, ...}` but `{1}` = `{1, 0, 0, 0, ...}`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no default value so it's garbage.

Comment: then to check the size of array filled would I have to initialize the entire array before inserting any elements? That way I would have a default to compare to.

Comment: @johnmurphy an arrays size needs to be declared for the program to compile. So you should know the size.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do what are you hoping to, not when the type is `int`.

The uninitialized elements of the array will have unpredictable values. In addition, accessing those elements is cause for undefined behavior.

You can initialize the elements of the array to a sentinel value at the time of allocation using:

```
int* ptr = new int[10]{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
```

Use whatever sentinel value works for you if `-1` does not.

Answer (score 3):

The default value of array is **indeterminate** means **garbage**.

> how can I check how much of the array is filled?

You cannot check, `C/C++` has no array bounds check. You have to do it yourself.You need to keep track of the data inserted by a user. When your counter reaches the size of the array, the array is full

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by a more C++ way. You can create **struct** or **class**, which contain your value and bool flag. Bool flag must be set to **false** in default constructor and set to **true** in operator=. There is ready implementation of such class - [boost.optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). std::optional will be in C++17.

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t nArr = 100;
    auto pArr = new boost::optional<int>[nArr];
    const size_t nInit = 30;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nInit; ++i)
    {
       pArr[i] = i;  //initialize nInit first values of pArr
    }
    size_t n = 0;
    for (; n < nArr; ++n)
    {
         if (!pArr[n].is_initialized()) break;
         // or more compact form:
         //if(!pArr[n]) break;
         assert(*pArr[n] == n);
    }
    std::cout << "nInit = " << nInit << ", n = " << n << std::endl;
    assert(nInit == n);
    delete[] pArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be pointed out the default is *uninitialized* only for basic types like `int`. `class`es will use their defined parameterless constructor. Here is a MWE that wraps an `int` in such a class. OP also asked about checking the values so that is here too:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Element {
    int Value;
    Element() : Value{42} {}
};

struct Array {
    Element Values[10];
};

int main() {
    Array array;
    
    for(Element element: array.Values)
        std::cout << element.Value << " ";
}
```

Note: *POD* (or *record*) classes, which have no custom constructor, will remain uninitialised. Non-POD classes that have no parameterless constructor cannot usually be held in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but in c++17 onwards there's the std::array class that can be used. In this class you have the option to use class functions such as std::array.fill(...)

```
std::array<int, 10> arr;
arr.fill(-1);
```

cpp docs: [cpp-docs](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/fill/)

This get's you closer to the experience from other languages such as Java and Python both having `Arrays.fill(arr, -1);` and `arr = [-1]*N` respectively to fill the array with non-default values.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the objects allocated by `new` are **default initialized**. This mean when you wrote:

```
int* array = new int[10]; //block of 10 uninitialized ints
```

Here, all of the 10 `int`s are **uninitialized**. That is, they have **indeterminate value**.

---

It is possible to **value initialize** the elements by adding an **empty** pair of parenthesis as shown below:

```
int* array = new int[10](); //block of 10 ints value initialized to 0
```

Here all of the 10 `int`s are initialized to `0`.

---

But note that although we can use empty parentheses to value initialize the elements of an array, we **cannot supply an element initializer** inside the parentheses. This means for example,

```
int* array = new int[10](55); // INVALID
```

The above statement is invalid because we cannot supply an element initializer inside the parenthesize.

You can use `std::fill_n` instead of supplying an element initializer inside the parentheses as shown below:

```
int* array = new int[10];                 //block of 10 uninitialized ints
std::fill_n(array, 10, 55);              // all elements will now hold 55
```